# Same date not put in database using ajax and call php page If match then display the alret message "This Date already exists in databse"

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, phpmyadmin, ajax4jsf

its ajax code:

```
    $("#adata").click(function() 
    {var tmp;
        tmp = "12354";
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
url: "some_page.php",
data: "insertdate:insertdate,exercise_ID:exercise_ID,userID:userID,exctype:exctype", 
dataType:"html",
async: false,
success: function(data)
            {

                $('#datepickers').html(data);

            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

This is the php file:some_page.php:

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("fit2startdemo");
$query=mysql_query("select * from jos_fitness_info where insertdate = '$insertdate'");  
if (mysqli_num_rows > 0) 
        {
                        echo "0"; //date exists 
        }   
        else
        {
                        echo "1"; //date not exists
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#adata').click(function() {
    var tmp;
    tmp = "12345";
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"POST",
        url: "some_page.php",
        data:     {insertdate:insertdate,exercise_ID:exercise_ID,userID:userID,exctype:exctype}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert(msg);
        $('#datepickers').html( msg );
    });
});
```

Try that

EDIT: so in your php code if the date matches then echo 'This Date already exists in Databse' and don't insert, else insert it

EDIT:

The problem was firstly that you were trying to send post data to, and retrieve a response from a php page that didn't exist. So first port of call when the callback function in an ajax request isn't working is whether or not it's actually communicating with the file (as if it's not the .done() function is never used as it's not successful.

Comment: Yes it's working my above code but u'r code put than not alert message displaying dear..

Comment: change it to alert('test') instead of alert('msg') and see if that alerts 'test'

Comment: Not display alert message..$('#adata').click(function() {
    var tmp;
    tmp = "12345";
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"POST",
        url: "some_page.php",
        data:{insertdate:insertdate,exercise_ID:exercise_ID,userID:userID,exctype:exctype},
    }).done(function('test') {
        alert('test');
        $('#datepickers').html('test');
    });
});
});

Comment: Ok so that would suggest that it's not returning a response from some_page.php - this is probably because the path to the file is wrong , so if this Javascript is in index.php then make sure some_page.php is a) named correctly, and b) in the same directory, if it's in a different folder called foo then the url would be: url:"foo/somepage.php". Also have you included Jquery ?

Comment: U'r right JohnnyFaldo some_page.php is not call so what can i do than solve this dear..

Comment: ok so change the  url: "some_page.php" to it's actual name, for example if the file is called 'check_exists.php' then change it to url: "check_exists.php"

Comment: Ok, could you add this to your page:  
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert('testing');
});

Comment: yes but alert message not displaying dear..give me ur gmail id i have send full file..if help me